# Making a variable cross module in Python - Within a class and function

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I'm trying to use a variable in other python modules, like this:

In `a.py`:

```
class Names:
    def userNames(self):
        self.name = 'Richard'
```

In `z.py`:

```
import a
d = a.Names.name
print d
```

However this doesn't recognise the variable `name` and the following error is received:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Names' has no attribute 'name'
```

Thanks

Comment: It should work if you are assigning it at the module level (not in a function).

Comment: Are you sure? This should work.

Comment: That code would work fine - are you sure that's your actual code?

Comment: Yep it works on my computer too

Comment: I've checked again and it's because I'm importing from is a `Tornado Framework` and the variable is within a class.

Comment: @user94628 Then that's completely different code from what you are showing.

Comment: This seems to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please give the X so answerers can solve your actual problem!

Comment: `def(userNames):` is invalid syntax. Please post your actual code.

Comment: Is the `name` static or is `Richard` a placeholder for dynamic processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of different scopes a variable can be bound to, which is what you seem to be confused about. Here are a few:

```
# a.py
a = 1 # (1) is module scope

class A:
    a = 2 # (2) is class scope

    def __init__(self, a=3): # (3) is function scope
        self.a = a           # (4) self.a is object scope

    def same_as_class(self):
        return self.a == A.a # compare object- and class-scope variables

    def same_as_module(self):
        return self.a == a   # compare object- and module-scope variables
```

Now see how these different variables (I only called them all `a` to make the point, please don't do this for real) are named, and how they all have different values:

```
>>> import a
>>> a.a
1 # module scope (1)
>>> a.A.a
2 # class scope (2)
>>> obj1 = a.A() # note the argument defaults to 3 (3)
>>> obj1.a       # and this value is bound to the object-scope variable (4)
3
>>> obj.same_as_class()
False             # compare the object and class values (3 != 2)

>>> obj2 = a.A(2) # now create a new object, giving an explicit value for (3)
>>> obj2.same_as_class()
True
```

Note we can also change any of these values:

```
>>> obj1.same_as_module()
False
>>> obj1.a = 1
>>> obj1.same_as_module()
True
```

---

For reference, your `z.py` above should probably look like:

```
import a
n = a.Names()
d.userNames()
d = n.name
print d
```

because `a.Name` is a *class*, but you're trying to refer to an *object-scope* variable. An *object* is an instance of a class: I've called my instance `n`. Now I have an object, I can  get at the object-scope variable. This is equivalent to Goranek's answer.

In terms of my previous example, you were trying to access `obj1.a` without having an `obj1` or anything like it. I'm not really sure how to make this clearer, without turning this into an introductory essay on OO and Python's type system.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation...it does help my understanding more. But in my question isn't: `d = a.Names.name` the same as `obj1 = a.A() obj.a`? As now it gives a : `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)`. Thanks

Comment: @user94628 - in the code you posted, `names` is an object-scope variable, like (4) above. You need an object (that is an _instance_ of `class Names`), because each object has its own value and they can be different. You're trying to refer to `Names.names`, but that doesn't exist - there is no equivalent of (2) above.

Comment: @Useless; Thanks for replying, so how could I do that. I'm getting lost here and would really appreciate help please. Thanks

Comment: Exactly the same way as I did for the object-scope variable above!

Comment: @Useless; Thanks this has given me a better understanding.

Answer (score 4):

> "I've checked again and it's because I'm importing from is a Tornado Framework and the variable is within a class."

Accordingly, your problem is not the one shown in your question.

If you actually want to access the variable of a class (and likely, you don't), then do this:

```
from othermodule import ClassName

print ClassName.var_i_want
```

You probably want to access the variable as held inside an instance:

```
from othermodule import ClassName, some_func

classnameinstance = some_func(blah)
print classnameinstance.var_i_want
```

**Update** Now that you have completely changed your question, here is the answer to your new question:

IN this code:

```
class Names:
    def userNames(self):
        name = 'Richard'
```

`name` is not a variable accessible outside of the activation of the method `userNames`. This is known as a local variable. You would create an instance variable by changing the code to:

```
def userNames(self):
        self.name = 'Richard'
```

Then, if you have an instance in a variable called `classnameinstance` you can do:

```
print classnameinstance.name
```

This will only work if the variable has been already created on the instance, as by calling `userNames`.

You don't need to import the class itself if there is some other way to receive instances of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've ammended my original answer to your reply, but still get the error: `AttributeError: type object 'Names' has no attribute 'name'`. I'm new to python, so I'm unsure what I have done wrong. Thanks

Comment: @user94628 That is because you are not doing what I suggest. You are doing something else. I show how a change would allow you to access the variable on an instance. You have made that change, and are attempting to access the variable on the class.

Comment: I know that this is probably something very simple, but I'm just not getting it. I'm confused about how `classnameinstance` comes about and how then it can be used in another module.

Comment: @user94628 `classnameinstance` comes about in the way shown - it is either created by a call to the class itself (see eg Goranek's answer, or useless'), or it is returned from a function or method. You create the variable, and you assign it the result of one of those calls, in the module in which you want to use it. If this is something you don't get, then I strongly recommend that you follow a tutorial (tedious as that usually is).

Comment: I'll have to agree with you and to get my head round variable binding, I'll look through some tutorials. I think I understand the concept, but Tornado is layering some more complexity to this I feel. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @user94628 I suggest you formulate a question demonstrating your problem uzing Tornado.

Answer (score 3):

## file:a.py

```
class Names:
    def userNames(self):
        self.name = 'Richard'
```

## file:z.py

```
import a
c = a.Names()
c.userNames()
what_you_want_is = c.name
```

Btw, this code makes no sense..but this is apparently what you want

## Better a.py

```
class Names:
    def userNames(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

## Better z.py

```
import a
c = a.Names()
c.userNames("Stephen or something")
what_you_want_is = c.name 
# what_you_want_is is "Stephen or something"
```

Comment: Can a guy who gave me a "-" be polite to say why?